# Problems with strcat

Tags: c, string, c-strings, strcat

I have a weird problem with `strca`t in C. This is the code:

```
char *getip(char n[])
{
    char *x[255];
    strcat(x, n);
    char *ip;
    ip = strtok(x, "/");
    return ip;
}

char *adrr(char n[])
{
    char *ip[255];
    strcat(ip, getip(n));
    return ip;
}

int main(void)
{
    scanf("%s", &n);
    printf("IP : %s\n", getip(n));
    printf("IP : %s", adrr(n));
}
```

The first `printf` returns exactly what I want it to return, and although the function `adrr` does seemingly nothing, the second `printf` returns some random character at the beginning and the end of what it should return.

Comment: `char *ip[255]` should be `char ip[255]` else it's an array of pointers. Well, not a string. And that won't work because you're returning a reference to a temporary

Comment: To begin with, change `char *x[255]` to `char x[255]`.

Comment: ..and initialise it so it can  be used by `strcat` with `char x[255] = {0};`

Comment: or use `strcpy` directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- you define `x` in `getip` as `char *x[255]`, it should be `char x[255]`
- you should initialize `x` before calling `strcat` or use `strcpy`.
- `ip` points to the local array `x`, returning it to the caller invokes undefined behavior as the array it points to cannot be used after the function returns.
- same problems in `adrr()`
- `n` is not defined in `main` for `scanf("%s",&n);`

The first function seems to work as expected out of pure luck, it may fail when compiled on a different system, or even just on a different day ;-)

Here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getip(char *dest, const char *src) {
    for (i = 0; src[i] != '\0' && src[i] != '/'; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}

int main(void) {
    char n[256];
    char ip[256];

    if (scanf("%255s", n) == 1) {
        printf("IP: %s\n", getip(ip, n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: n is declared global . and when I define x as " char x[255]=""; " the getip function won't work anymore

Comment: @Andrei: Bullet #3 refers to this problem specifically. In order to resolve it, you need to either declare `x` as `static` (which means that you might run into concurrency problems if you call this function from different threads), or allocate this memory block dynamically (which means that you will have to deallocate it at a later point in the execution of the program).

Comment: Thanks to both of you , I just made it static char x[255]={0}; , used strcpy and now it seems to work .

Comment: @Andrei: be aware that making the array `static` in the function is not the correct solution.  It works but it is sloppy and error prone.  You should either pass a destination array for the result or allocate memory and return the allocated pointer.  Both solutions have different semantics.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks again , I will use the solution you provided

Comment: @Andrei you moved from underkill to overkill! Better to understand the implications of each of the three things you did: static, initialise, strcpy.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I agree beginners should understand all these implications, but it is high time tutorials should stop subjecting them to the horrors of `strtok()`, `scanf()` and static local variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. n in main does not exist
2. I think you think about char buf[10] but write char *buf[10]
3. If you return a pointer to a memory that only exists inside a function than the result is undefined. Make it static or dynamic.

Comment: "Make it static or dynamic" should be "**Declare** it static or **allocate** it dynamically".